# Spring Boot - How to start my Spring Boot Application from sister module in a multi-module project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

I have a multi-module project with two projects: *backend* and *client*. The backend is a normal Spring Boot Rest API, nothing special. The *client* module is just a Java Library using the Rest API.

The backend has packaging of "war" as the backend as it uses JSPs, too and needs to be deployed to a servlet container. The backend is still easily testable with @SpringBootTest.

Now I want to have some integration tests inside the *client* module using the backend module as a sandbox server.

To use all the backend classes in the client module I added

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and configured the backend as a test dependency in client with classes

In my client/src/test/java I have a helper class which starts up the backend module

```
@Configuration  
public class SandboxServer {

  @Bean
  public ConfigurableApplicationContext backend() {
    return 
      new SpringApplicationBuilder(BackendApplication.class)
      .sources(SandboxServerConfig.class)
      .run("spring.profiles.active=sandbox")
  }
}
```

The profile "sandbox" is used to setup a test database etc. But I had more problems. First problem was regarding the document root, so I configured it:

```
public class SandboxServerConfig 
  implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {
  @Override
  public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
    factory.setDocumentRoot(new File("../backend/src/main/webapp"));
  }
}
```

But it still does not work as Spring is not picking up backend/src/main/resources/application.properties

That might be correct as it is not in the root classpath of the client module.

So it does not really work. I guess it is not possible to just start up the sibling module in an Integration test.

How can I achieve to start up the sibling spring boot module for integration testing? What is the best practice for szenarios like this?

Comment: What is the specific reason you have decided to deploy to a separate servlet container rather than use an embedded server - which is the recommended deployment mechanism for Spring Boot applications. It seems that this decision has painted you into a corner and let you some really odd workarounds.

Comment: It is an embedded server. But it uses some JSP pages so I still have a src/main/webapp Folder.

Comment: If it's an embedded server the whole `.war` thing is entirely spurious. A .war` is deployed on an external servlet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a much more solid solution. In my sibling Project "frontend" I have a Component which is starting up the backend server in integration mode if and only if it is not already running.

Benefits:

- The real WAR is tested
- You can start the WAR before in your IDE and let the tests run fast
- If you run it with maven it is started up before all tests only once
- No build configuration needed (like pre-integration in maven)
- process is seperated from Junit runtime so no hassle with complex setups.

Drawbacks:

- You need to build the package before you can run any integration test in the frontend. But hey, you should build your package before you test it. That's what integration test is all about.

And here is my SandboxServerProcess.class.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;   
import javax.annotation.*;
import javax.annotation.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

@Component
@Profile("integration")
public class SandboxServerProcess {
    private static final String WAR = "../backend/target/backend.war";
    private final static int PORT = 8081;
    private boolean startedByMe;

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() throws Exception {
        if (isStarted()) {
            return;
        }
        testWarExists();
        packagedWar("start");
        if (waitForStartup()) {
            startedByMe = true;
            return;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Sandbox Server not started");
    }

    private void testWarExists() {
        File file = new File(WAR);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("WAR does not exist:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stop() throws IOException {
        if (startedByMe) {
            packagedWar("stop");
        }
    }

    private void packagedWar(String command) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
        builder.environment().put("MODE", "service");
        builder.environment().put("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", "integration");
        builder.environment().put("APP_NAME", "backend");
        builder.environment().put("PID_FOLDER", "./");
        builder.environment().put("LOG_FOLDER", "./");
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        commands.add(WAR);
        commands.add(command);
        builder.command(commands);
        builder.inheritIO();
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        builder.start();
    }

    private boolean isStarted() {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            InetSocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", PORT);
            socket.connect(sa, 500);
            logger.warn("SandboxServer is started");
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean waitForStartup() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
            if (isStarted()) {
                return true;
            }
            logger.warn("SandboxServer not yet ready, tries: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eeew. This is rather nasty. Why not just use `@SpringBootTest` or even `SpringApplication.run`?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `application.properties` location using [TestPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = BlaApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="/path/to/backend/src/main/resources/application.properties")
public class ExampleApplicationTests {

}
```

Comment: Good idea, but setting TestProperties affects the test itself. I give it a try but it feels like messing it up.